# Parallelizing lines

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, projective-space

Let $n \geq 1$ be an integer, and $L_1,\ldots,L_n$ be $n$ lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which are pairwise disjoint. Is it possible to move all $n$ lines continuously so that they never cross, and so as to send the line $L_k$ to $\{k\} \times \mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$?

This seems instinctively true, but I don't see any slick proof right now. The problem is that the space of affine lines is $4$-dimensional, while "crossing a given line" is $3$-dimensional, so codimension $1$. Hence, if I try to move each line once at a time, it seems entirely possible that a set of badly placed lines cages off a portion of space, and that the remaining lines can't be moved around freely.

Bonus question : what is the least number of pairwise disjoint lines $(L_k)$ I need so that the space of lines which cross no $L_k$ is disconnected?

Comment: it's not clear what you have in mind by "cage off a portion of space"... any line which does not intersect another must have $\varepsilon$ space to maneuver in all directions. like parked-in cars, we can winnow lines out of tight spaces incrementally. (nothing formal, just explaining my intuition for why I think this is true)

Comment: @MichaelChirico I am not so sure this always works. Pictures 6 lines that form two triangles, one on top of the other, with some distance. Pick all the lines to be parallel to the $x,y$ plane and have very small distance from eachother in each of the triangles. Now consider a line that goes through the middle of these two triangles, vertically down to the $x,y$ plane. I am not sure you'll be able to move that 7th line out of the two triangles fixing the other 6?

Comment: I didn't emphasize that I don't think you can necessarily do it one-by-one--it may have to be an iterative/back-and-forth process. i hope it's clear that we can parallelize the lines in your example--but i think you're right that if we keep the other 6 _fixed_, the 7th is indeed stuck.

Comment: How about this as an idea: you can more or less define what it means for a line to be _on top_ of all the others with respect to a given direction (?). This should allow you to move that line as far away as you want from the rest. Now whaterver movement happens for the rest of the lines would look as if they all intersect eachother at the origin -for the far away line. Then, maybe some induction where if a movement is obstructed by the far away line, you can move the whole _central_ cluster to avoid the obstruction...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really liked this question! The wikipedia page for [configurations of skew lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_lines#Configurations) has a reference to this beautiful [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0611374) by Viro & Viro that -among other things- answers the first question positively!

Here is how the idea worsk: Consider two parallel planes in general position (that is, not paralled to any of the lines). In the first plane fix the points of intersection of the lines and the plane. In the second plane make a mark (relative to that plane) at each point the lines intersect it. Then move the second plane vertically far away from the first and allow the lines to move as their point of intersection with the second plane should always be the corresponding marked point.

You can also think about it as drilling a small hole in the second plane, so that when it moves it forces the whole configuration of lines to change with it. In a sense the moving plane is like a comb that moves all lines in parallel position.

Now, we need to check that during this process the lines would never intersect. It is enough to check for a single pair of lines. This isn't very difficult to do:

First assume the planes are parallel to the $x,y$-plane. Now call the fixed points in the first plane $A=(a_1,a_2,0)$ and $B=(b_1,b_2,0)$ and the moving marked points $C=(c_1,c_2,t)$ and $D=(d_1,d_2,t)$. Now, the lines $AC$ and $BD$ intersect if the following system has a solution in $x$ and $y$ $$a_1+x(c_1-a_1)=b_1+y(d_1-b_1)$$ $$ a_2+x(c_2-a_2)=b_2+y(d_2-b_2)$$ $$0+x(t-0)=0+y(t-0)$$ Now this forces $x=y$ and then $$\frac{b_1-a_1}{c_1-a_1-d_1+b_1}=\frac{b_2-a_2}{c_2-a_2-d_2+b_2}$$ But notice that this does not depend on $t$! That is, if the lines didn't initially cross, they will never cross during the *combing motion* imposed by the moving second plane.

Comment: This is also a nice reference for -the homework problem- of calculating the homology of the complement of $n$ non-intersecting lines: http://rene.ma.utexas.edu/users/sadun/F09/prelim/hwsol11.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much! This is absolutely beautiful. Initially, I wanted to compute the homotopy group of the complement of $n$ non-intersecting lines, and then I found this problem to be in itself quite nice.

Comment: Glad to have helped! I was also surprised by how neat the proof is. Your bonus question is also cool; I think the answer should be $4$ or $5$ but can't really come up with anything apart from my $6$ lines example in the comments above.